# Why does my Javascript object outputs its method as typeof function instead of its result?

Tags: javascript, object

Why does Javascript return the baz method as 'typeof function' instead of its result and how can I output the result instead?

```
    var someObject  = new Object();
    someObject.foo  = $('#someElement'),
    someObject.bar  = $('#someOtherElement'),
    someObject.baz  = function() {
        return 'Hello world!';
    }

    console.log(someObject.baz); // Outputs: function (){return"Hello world!"}
```

Eventually I want to let baz calculate the height difference of the elements in foo and bar but so far I haven't been able to access the calculated result in baz or any other result like the string in the code example above.

Comment: To get the results, you need to *invoke* the function, as follows: `someObject.baz()`.

Comment: you are refering the function not calling it

Comment: All equally thanks for the answer! Accepted the first one that wasn't posted as a comment. I'm just going to live on a mountain now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is holding a reference to the function.
If you want to return the result then you have to execute it

```
ex: someObject.baz()
```

Answer (score 0):

call the function

console.log(someObject.baz())